# set and create paragraph style in swift

Tags: xcode, text, swift, pdf-generation, text-alignment

I am trying to port an objective C method to draw text in a PDF context to Swift.
I could convert most of the code, but the following lines are giving me a problem.
Some help in the conversion would be welcome.
Here the Objective C code:

```
-(void)drawText:(NSString *)textToDraw context:(CGContextRef)myPDFContext textcolor:(NSColor *)textcolor  textfont:(NSFont*)textfont textbox:(CGRect)boxsize pagesize:(CGSize)pageSize {

   //     .........

   //    create paragraph style and assign text alignment to it
   CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTJustifiedTextAlignment;
   CTParagraphStyleSetting _settings[] = {    {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment} };
   CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(_settings, sizeof(_settings) / sizeof(_settings[0]));

   //    set paragraph style attribute
   CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr, CFRangeMake(0,   CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle);

   //     .........
}

 // The following lines are my try in Swift, but this gives errors:
func DrawText(textToDraw:String, myPDFContext:CGContextRef, textcolor:NSColor,    textfont:NSFont, boxsize:CGRect, pagesize:CGSize) {
  var alignment = CTTextAlignment.TextAlignmentLeft
  let alignmentSetting = CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec:  CTParagraphStyleSpecifier.Alignment, valueSize: sizeof(alignment), value: &alignment)
  let paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(alignmentSetting, 1)
  //.......
```

If this is solved I could post the complete method in Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
var alignment = CTTextAlignment.TextAlignmentLeft
let alignmentSetting = [CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec: .Alignment, valueSize: UInt(sizeofValue(alignment)), value: &alignment)]
let paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(alignmentSetting, 1)
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle)
```

I made the following modifications:

1. I changed `sizeof(alignment)` to `UInt(sizeofValue(alignment))` because `sizeof` in Swift only takes a type (such as `sizeof(Int)`).  The `UInt()` is a constructor that turns the `Int` returned by `sizeofValue` into the `UInt` needed by this call.
2. I make `alignmentSetting` into an array so that it could be passed to an `UnsafePointer` of that type.  This also better matches the original version.
3. I changed `CTParagraphStyleSpecifier.Alignment` to just `.Alignment` since the first part isn't needed since `spec` is of type `CTParagraphStyleSpecifier`.

The hardcoded `1` is OK in this case because you are passing just one value, but the more general solution would be to do:

```
let paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(alignmentSetting, UInt(alignmentSetting.count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the full working method based on the corrections and help.

```
func drawText(textToDraw:String, myPDFContext:CGContextRef, textcolor:NSColor,  textfont:NSFont, boxsize:CGRect, pagesize:CGSize) {
    let _font = NSFont(name:textfont.fontName, size:textfont.pointSize )
    if (_font == nil) {
        println("Font [\(textfont)] does not exist")
        return
    }

    let myBoxWidth = boxsize.size.width
    let myBoxHeight = boxsize.size.height
    let myBoxxpos = boxsize.origin.x
    let myBoxypos = boxsize.origin.y
    let frameRect = CGRectMake(myBoxxpos, myBoxypos,myBoxWidth,myBoxHeight);

     let framePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
     CGPathAddRect(framePath, nil, frameRect);

     //    create attributed string
     let attrStr = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
     CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, 0), textToDraw);

    //    create font
    let font = CTFontCreateWithName(textfont.fontName, textfont.pointSize, nil);

 var alignment = CTTextAlignment.TextAlignmentLeft
    let alignmentSetting = [CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec: .Alignment, valueSize: UInt(sizeofValue(alignment)), value: &alignment)]
    //let paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(alignmentSetting, 1)
    let paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(alignmentSetting, UInt(alignmentSetting.count))
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle)

 //    set font attribute
 CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTFontAttributeName, font);

 //    set color attribute
 CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrStr,CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(attrStr)), kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,textcolor.CGColor);

 // Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter.
 let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrStr);

 // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
 let currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
 let frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, nil);

 // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
 // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
 CGContextSetTextMatrix(myPDFContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

 // Draw the frame.
 CTFrameDraw(frameRef, myPDFContext);
}
```

Comment: Rather than posting @vacavama 's answer again, you should accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks, i was not aware of this. Thanks, vacavama.

Comment: Ah, no, actually I meant to accept vacama's answer, since yours is just a duplicate of it, as far as I can see.